# Is assigning value to a struct atomic in go?

Tags: go

I have two structs `App` and `Config`.

```golang
type App struct {
    cfg Config
}
```

```golang
type Config struct {
    dbHost   string
    dbPort   int
    user     string
    password string
}
```

and two methods defined on App to update and read `cfg` field.

```golang
func (app *App) UpdateConfig(newCfg Config) {
    app.cfg = newCfg
}

func (app *App) GetConfig() Config {
    return app.cfg
}
```

If only one goroutine is calling `UpdateConfig` and multiple goroutines are reading the config via `GetConfig` method, should I protect access to `app.cfg` with a mutex?

Edit: Reader goroutines are calling `GetConfig` in a for loop. Seeing the updated value of the config "instantly" is not a requirement.  It is ok for the readers to see the updated value of the cfg in the next iteration.

So I am rephrasing my question : Is it possible for a reader to see the partially updated config value?

Comment: Nothing is "atomic" unless you use `sync/atomic`, and concurrent reads and writes are always a race condition.

Comment: If you do not use sync/atomic or a mutex, then there is no guarantee on when the reader goroutines will see the change after write happens, if ever.

Comment: Any concurrent access where at least one access is a write is a race condition and the behavior is undefined. Synchronize access, for example using a mutex.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have edited the question.

Comment: Even if you don't need to see the updated variable, it is still a race. There is no safe data-race. Use `sync/atomic` to read/write. It works with very little overhead -- a memory barrier, no locking involved there. The reader will not see a partially updated value. The problem is that, it may never see the updated value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you shouldn't expect to see all or none of the updated config if you modify it asynchronously.

Go tries to be reasonable (even if it doesn't formally guarantee it); if you update a word-sized object on an architecture where word-sized updates can't tear, then you'll see the update or not even if you don't synchronize. (This differs from C and C++, where undefined behavior means the compiler can legitimately do anything). But here, `Config` is a large value, and there's no cheap way go could guarantee the all-or-nothing update you want (without performing some synchronization itself).

But yes, you should use a mutex to protect the config. If there's too much contention and you don't mind old configs for a bit, then you can poll the official config periodically and update a local copy when it changes.

Pragmatically, mutexes are fast, and it's almost always better to have async-correct code even if it's a little slower. For example, if you don't have async-correct code, you can't easily use the race detector to find other genuine problems, even if your code behaves as you want.

Comment: "Go tries to be reasonable (even if it doesn't formally guarantee it)" - which means you should treat it as it is, undefined behavior, and not rely on it. Even with a word-sized value, races should not be accepted.

Comment: And if coordination (i.e. "happens before") isn't required, and you have word-sized values, still use atomic. They can compile to noops if the architecture doesn't require them.